# Parse CASE WHEN statements with sqlparse

Tags: python, sql-parser

I have the following SQL query and would like to parse it using [`sqlparse`](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse)

```
import sqlparse

query =  """
select SUM(case when(A.dt_unix<=86400
                     and B.flag="V") then 1
           end) as TEST_COLUMN_1,
       SUM(case when(A.Amt - B.Amt > 0
                     and B.Cat1 = "A"
                     and (B.Cat2 = "M"
                          or B.Cat3 = "C"
                          or B.Cat4 = "B")
                     and B.Cat5 is NULL) then 1
           end) as TEST_COLUMN_2
from test_table A
left join test_table_2 as B on A.ID=B.ID
where A.DT >B.DT
group by A.ID
"""

query_tokens = sqlparse.parse(query)[0].tokens
print(query_tokens)
```

would give all the tokens included in the SQL statement:

```
[<Newline ' ' at 0x7FAA62BD9F48>, <DML 'select' at 0x7FAA62BE7288>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x7FAA62BE72E8>, <IdentifierList 'SUM(ca...' at 0x7FAA62BF7CF0>, <Newline ' ' at 0x7FAA62BF6288>, <Keyword 'from' at 0x7FAA62BF62E8>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x7FAA62BF6348>, <Identifier 'test_t...' at 0x7FAA62BF7570>, <Newline ' ' at 0x7FAA62BF64C8>, <Keyword 'left j...' at 0x7FAA62BF6528>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x7FAA62BF6588>, <Identifier 'test_t...' at 0x7FAA62BF7660>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x7FAA62BF67C8>, <Keyword 'on' at 0x7FAA62BF6828>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x7FAA62BF6888>, <Comparison 'A.ID=B...' at 0x7FAA62BF7B10>, <Newline ' ' at 0x7FAA62BF6B88>, <Where 'where ...' at 0x7FAA62BF28B8>, <Keyword 'group' at 0x7FAA62BD9E88>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x7FAA62BD93A8>, <Keyword 'by' at 0x7FAA62BD9EE8>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x7FAA62C1CEE8>, <Identifier 'A.ID' at 0x7FAA62BF2F48>, <Newline ' ' at 0x7FAA62BF6C48>]
```

How can I parse these tokens in order to process `CASE WHEN` statements in a way that I can extract all the conditions and maintain their precedence as defined by the use of parentheses. I was not able to find any relevant examples in the documentation.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Having written an answer, I now am looking at [this project instead](https://github.com/mozilla/moz-sql-parser), which remarks that *sqlparse does not provide a tree, rather a list of tokens.*. While that statement is not entirely accurate, `sqlparse` doesn't make it easy to use the token tree.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've had a look at mozzila's project but it raises recursion exceptions when more complex SQL statements are parsed.

Comment: Crumbs, `moz-sql-parser` actually raises a recursion exception when asked to parse your sample statement.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Exactly.

Comment: That's [this bug report](https://github.com/mozilla/moz-sql-parser/issues/41).

Comment: Raising the recursion limit does give me the parse tree now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Right. It seems good but still has some issues; for example `IS (NOT) NULL` is parsed as `missing`.

Comment: Yup, it's not ideal either, and I don't see any other libraries filling this void either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do you have any recursive parser in mind that would be useful for parsing the JSON output of `moz-sql-parser`?

Comment: Its already structured data, just traverse the dictionaries and lists, with a stack perhaps.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The project is indeed a little underdocumented. I looked at the [examples](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/tree/master/examples) and scanned the source code a little. The documentation unfortunately doesn't include all methods on the `Token` and `TokenList` classes that are useful for this task.

For example, an important but omitted method is the [`TokenList.get_sublists()` method](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/blob/47768597924d88cec426e379b4afae8b58491956/sqlparse/sql.py#L201-L204), which lets you traverse over nested token lists more easily than other methods do; the [`TokenList.flatten()`](https://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/analyzing/#sqlparse.sql.TokenList.flatten) method only yields *ungrouped* tokens in the tree, whereas `CASE` is a grouped token, so going purely by the documentation you might find it hard to do something useful with the parsed token tree.

Another handy method that I noticed in the codebase is the [`TokenList._pprint_tree()` method](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/blob/master/sqlparse/sql.py#L162-L178), which dumps out the current token tree to stdout. This is very helpful when trying to write code that analyses the tree.

All in all my overall impression of `sqlparse` is that it is less of a parsing library than a tool to re-format SQL. It includes a good parser but doesn't include the tools necessary to make *general use* of the tree it produces.

What is really missing in the library is a base *node visitor class* such as that provided by the [Python `ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor), or a tree node walker, again like the [`ast` module provides](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.walk). Either is easy enough to build yourself, luckily:

```
from collections import deque
from sqlparse.sql import TokenList

class SQLTokenVisitor:
    def visit(self, token):
        """Visit a token."""
        method = 'visit_' + type(token).__name__
        visitor = getattr(self, method, self.generic_visit)
        return visitor(token)

    def generic_visit(self, token):
        """Called if no explicit visitor function exists for a node."""
        if not isinstance(token, TokenList):
            return
        for tok in token:
            self.visit(tok)

def walk_tokens(token):
    queue = deque([token])
    while queue:
        token = queue.popleft()
        if isinstance(token, TokenList):
            queue.extend(token)
        yield token
```

Now you can use either to access the `Case` nodes:

```
statement, = sqlparse.parse(query)

class CaseVisitor(SQLTokenVisitor):
    """Build a list of SQL Case nodes

      The .cases list is a list of (condition, value) tuples per CASE statement

    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.cases = []

    def visit_Case(self, token):
        branches = []
        for when, then_ in token.get_cases():
            branches
        self.cases.append(token.get_cases())

visitor = CaseVisitor()
visitor.visit(statement)
cases = visitor.cases
```

or

```
statement, = sqlparse.parse(query)

cases = []
for token in walk_tokens(statement):
    if isinstance(token, sqlparse.sql.Case):
        cases.append(token.get_cases())
```

The difference between the `walk_tokens()` and `NodeVisitor` patterns is negligible in this example, but we are simply extracting the separated tokens for each of the `CASE` statements, with no processing of the `WHEN ... THEN ...` tokens. In the `NodeVisitor` pattern you'd set more attributes on the current visitor instance to 'switch gears' and capture further information about those subtree tokens in more `visit_....` methods, which may be easier to follow than a nested `for` loop over a generator.

On the other hand, with the `walk_tokens()` generator, if you create a separate variable to reference the generator, you can hand over iteration to helper functions:

```
all_tokens = walk_tokens(stamement)
for token in walk_tokens(statement):
    if isinstance(token, sqlparse.sql.Case):
        branches = extract_branches(all_tokens)
```

where `extract_branches` would further iterate until it came to the end of the case statement.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Martin's [fantastic] answer, I think that Newline and Whitespace  should be ignored when visiting the nodes.

```
    ...
    ...
    def visit(self, token):
        """Visit a token."""
        if not token.is_whitespace:
            visitor = getattr(self, method, self.generic_visit)
            return visitor(token)
```