# Is there a good way to parse sql case statement?

Tags: python, sql-parser

The goal is to parse the sql statement in Python, and I have some difficulties using sqlparse to parse the case statement. I have tried the method in this link [Parse CASE WHEN statements with sqlparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54982118/parse-case-when-statements-with-sqlparse), but the result becomes messy when the data set becomes large. For example, if the case statement is like:

```
CASE
           WHEN ticket.status IN ('new',
                                  'assigned')
                AND ticket_custom.ticket = 3 THEN “Win”
```

the parsed result is shown as below:

```
([<Keyword 'WHEN' at 0x1870AFBA6A8>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBA708>, <Comparison 'ticket...' at 0x1870AFF55C8>, <Newline ' ' at 0x1870AFBC8E8>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBC948>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBC9A8>, <Whitespace ' ' 
at 0x1870AFBCA08>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBCA68>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBCAC8>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBCB28>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBCB88>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBCBE8>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBCC48>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBCCA8>, 
<Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBCD08>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBCD68>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBCDC8>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBCE28>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBCE88>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBCEE8>, <Keyword 'AND' at 0x1870AFBCF48>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBCFA8>, <Comparison 'ticket...' at 0x1870AFF5648>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBD2E8>], [<Keyword 'THEN' at 0x1870AFBD348>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBD3A8>, <Error '“' at 0x1870AFBD408>, <Identifier 'Win' at 0x1870AFEF048>, <Error '”' at 0x1870AFBD4C8>, <Newline ' ' at 0x1870AFBD528>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBD588>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBD5E8>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBD648>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBD6A8>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBD708>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBD768>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBD7C8>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBD828>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBD888>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x1870AFBD8E8>, <Whitespace ' ' 
at 0x1870AFBD948>]),
```

You can imagine what the result would become when the sql statement becomes complex.
And the result I would like to have is actually similiar to the way that sql_metadata parse the subqueries:

```
{'case statement name':"case statement content" }
```

the sql_metadata and sqlparse could parse subqueries like this but not for the case statement, is there any other way to do that in Python?

Here is the complex example:

```
SELECT '%c%' AS Chapter = 
    CASE
           WHEN ticket.status IN ('new',
                                  'assigned')
                AND ticket_custom.ticket = 3 THEN “Win”
           WHEN ticket.status IN ('new',
                                  'assigned')
                AND ticket_custom.ticket = 2 THEN “Lose”
           WHEN ticket.status IN ('new',
                                  'assigned')
                AND ticket_custom.ticket = 1 THEN “Draw”
           WHEN ticket.status IN ('new',
                                  'assigned')
                AND EmployeeConsolidated.id= 49887 THEN “Undefined”
       END AS Feature,
       ticket_custom.ticket,
       ticket_custom.mn,
       ticket_custom.value,
       ticket_custom.category,
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN ticket.status IN ('new', 'assigned') THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) AS NEW,
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN ticket.status IN ('new', 'assigned') THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) AS OLD,
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN ticket.status='closed' THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) AS 'Closed',
       count(id) AS Total,
       EmployeeConsolidated.id,
       EmployeeConsolidated.rate,
       ticket.id AS _id
FROM engine.ticket
INNER JOIN engine.ticket_custom ON ticket.id = ticket_custom.ticket
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT e.employee_id AS "Employee #" ,
          e.first_name || ' ' || e.last_name AS "Name" ,
          e.email AS "Email" ,
          e.phone_number AS "Phone" ,
          TO_CHAR(e.hire_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "Hire Date" ,
          TO_CHAR(e.salary, 'L99G999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,'' NLS_CURRENCY = ''$''') AS "Salary" ,
          e.commission_pct AS "Comission %" ,
          'works as ' || j.job_title || ' in ' || d.department_name || ' department (manager: ' || dm.first_name || ' ' || dm.last_name || ') and immediate supervisor: ' || m.first_name || ' ' || m.last_name AS "Current Job" ,
          TO_CHAR(j.min_salary, 'L99G999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,'' NLS_CURRENCY = ''$''') || ' - ' || TO_CHAR(j.max_salary, 'L99G999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,'' NLS_CURRENCY = ''$''') AS "Current Salary" ,
          l.street_address || ', ' || l.postal_code || ', ' || l.city || ', ' || l.state_province || ', ' || c.country_name || ' (' || r.region_name || ')' AS "Location" ,
          jh.job_id AS "History Job ID" ,
          'worked from ' || TO_CHAR(jh.start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' to ' || TO_CHAR(jh.end_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' as ' || jj.job_title || ' in ' || dd.department_name || ' department' AS "History Job Title"
   FROM employees e -- to get title of current job_id

   JOIN jobs j ON e.job_id = j.job_id -- to get name of current manager_id

   LEFT JOIN employees m ON e.manager_id = m.employee_id -- to get name of current department_id

   LEFT JOIN departments d ON d.department_id = e.department_id -- to get name of manager of current department
-- (not equal to current manager and can be equal to the employee itself)

   LEFT JOIN employees dm ON d.manager_id = dm.employee_id -- to get name of location

   LEFT JOIN locations l ON d.location_id = l.location_id
   LEFT JOIN countries c ON l.country_id = c.country_id
   LEFT JOIN regions r ON c.region_id = r.region_id -- to get job history of employee

   LEFT JOIN job_history jh ON e.employee_id = jh.employee_id -- to get title of job history job_id

   LEFT JOIN jobs jj ON jj.job_id = jh.job_id -- to get namee of department from job history

   LEFT JOIN departments dd ON dd.department_id = jh.department_id
   ORDER BY e.employee_id) AS EmployeeConsolidated ON e.employee_id = engine.ide
WHERE ticket_custom.name='chapter'
  AND ticket_custom.value LIKE '%c%'
  AND TYPE='New material'
  AND milestone='1.1.12'
  AND component NOT LIKE 'internal_engine'
GROUP BY ticket.id
```

The desired output should be like this:

```
{'Feature':"Case When ticket.status IN ('new','assigned') and ticket_custom.ticket = 3 then “Win” When  ticket.status IN ('new','assigned') and ticket_custom.ticket = 2 then “Lose” When ticket.status IN  ('new','assigned') and ticket_custom.ticket = 1 then “Draw” When ticket.status IN   ('new','assigned') and EmployeeConsolidated.id= 49887 then “Undeﬁned” End as Feature," },
{'New':"SUM(CASE WHEN ticket.status IN ('new','assigned') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as New," },
{'Old':"SUM(CASE WHEN ticket.status IN ('new','assigned') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Old," },
.......
```

Comment: Is there an RDBMS where you can use both `'` and `"` for defining string literals? I see an error in your sqlparse output as a result of that issue.

Comment: As far as your question goes, can you share a complex case statement and what your desired result would be after you parse it. It's not clear to me from your question.

Comment: Hi I have add a complex example, hope it would clarify better. And also yes that is an error, i will fix it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SQLGlot](https://github.com/tobymao/sqlglot) to parse your query and iterate or find different expression types.

Parsing your original example yields an AST.

```
(CASE ifs:
  (IF this:
    (AND this:
      (IN this:
        (COLUMN this:
          (IDENTIFIER this: status, quoted: False), table:
          (IDENTIFIER this: ticket, quoted: False)), expressions:
        (LITERAL this: new, is_string: True),
        (LITERAL this: assigned, is_string: True)), expression:
      (EQ this:
        (COLUMN this:
          (IDENTIFIER this: ticket, quoted: False), table:
          (IDENTIFIER this: ticket_custom, quoted: False)), expression:
        (LITERAL this: 3, is_string: False))), true:
    (LITERAL this: Win, is_string: True)))
```